# Using Roles for Validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to use the roles used for `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected`? I'm trying to setup a validation that only executes when not an admin (like this sort of http://launchware.com/articles/whats-new-in-edge-scoped-mass-assignment-in-rails-3-1). For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def validate(record)
     unless # role.admin?
       record.errors[:name] << 'Wrong length' if ...
     end
  end
end

user = User.create({ ... }, role: "admin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this and digging through the source code, it appears that the role passed in when creating an Active Record object is exposed through a protected method `mass_assignment_role`. Thus, the code in question can be re-written as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def validate(record)
    unless mass_assignment_role.eql? :admin
      record.errors[:name] << 'Wrong length' if ...
    end
  end
end

user = User.create({ ... }, role: "admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure can would be something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role

 validates :record_validation

 def record_validation
   unless self.role == "admin"
     errors.add(:name, "error message") if ..
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options :if => :is_admin? do |admin|
    admin.validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 10 } #sample validations
    admin.validates :email, :presence => true #sample validations
  end
end
```

[5.4 Grouping conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)